# Error with android.R

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling, syntax-error

Hi I am developing an android application, nothing fancy just something small for college. Where I use R I recieve an error on the final bit. example R.id.**mediAware**
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code if that helps:

```
package com.example.medicalapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.medicalapp.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mediAware);
        ImageView splash_image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mediAware2);


        Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein2);


        fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){
            }
        });
        splash_image.startAnimation(fade1);
        splash_image2.startAnimation(fade2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do a "clean build" and then a rebuild. Something went wrong with referencing to the R file

Comment: I did a clean and rebuild and now all activities contain errors with R

Comment: Most of the times when you have an error of that kind is because there is an error somewhere else in your XML layout, check your layout and manifest for any coding mistakes.

Comment: No nothing in the manifest file. If i very simply create a new project the first is perfect by default, if I add a second activity and dont edit anything immediately I receive errors with anything related to R without manipulating any code in the second activity

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I was missing the R.java file. To add the file i simply created a folder in src called gen and then cleaned the project, this created the R.java file and removed my errors, appreciate the help that was given